# Area51: a commitment shows up on the user's profile but not on the proposal itself

Tags: bug, area-51

According to [their profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/161531/thebitbyte?tab=stats), user TheBitByte has committed to the Literature proposal at Area 51 (and they hadn't 12 hours ago, so they must be one of the few most recent committers):

[image: from profile]

But if you look at [the list of committers on the proposal itself](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top), TheBitByte doesn't appear there at all:

[image: from proposal]

Seems a bit of a long period (11 hours and counting) to be a caching issue, especially since I've been watching this proposal closely and new committers tend to show up pretty quickly when refreshing the front page of the proposal. So is this some kind of bug? And if so, are there more people who *have* committed (at least according to their profiles) but aren't showing up on the list of committers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user hasn't verified their email address yet. Their commitment won't count until they complete the verification process. The FAQ clearly states this:

> #### How do I refer users?
>
> If you invite a friend, be sure to use the special referral link in the Share It popup. If the user commits to the site after using your link, we'll record you as the referrer. Make sure they verify their email address, otherwise their commitment won't count.

We don't want users showing up and just clicking a button with a fake email and then disappearing forever - that causes proposals to fail because they just *look* like they have a committed user base when they don't.